# Integral of $r^2\sin\left(\arccos(\frac{R^2+r^2-D^2}{2 R r})\right)$ where $r$ belongs to $(D-R,R)$?

Tags: integration

The integral of $r^2\sin\left(\arccos(\frac{R^2+r^2-D^2}{2 R r})\right)$ where $r$ belongs to $(D-R,R)$ is obtained from Wolfram. I have attached the answer

[image: Answer]

but the problem is that when I obtained the definite integral after putting values of $r$ and fix $R=1$ and $D$ ranges from $(R,2R)$, it gives imaginary answer.

Answer (score 0):

$D,r,R$ must satisfy 
$$0< r^2+R^2-D^2\leq 2 r R$$
Otherwise the argument of the arccos becomes greater than $1$ and is no more real

Hope this helps